# Download .msi to client and run automatically

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, wix, windows-installer

Here's the requirement:
1. An uninstall .msi is packaged and placed in IIS server location.
2. The user would be presented with a html page or asp.net page with a link shown in the page.
3. Clicking link in the page, the .msi should be downloaded to the client machine and automatically run.

My main doubt is whether, we can download and automatically run the .msi.

Please share different approaches to implement this requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the term "uninstall .msi" to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. Thats what you call 'malicious scripts' unfortunately. Only if he downloads it manually, and runs it, it will be installed.

Comment: It sounds like he's looking for a ClickOnce type behavior.

Comment: InstallShield used to have a feature called Install From The Web.  This was an ActiveX control that would automatically enable and when clicked start the installation in a streaming sort of way.  And yes, it didn't end well and isn't really possible today.

Answer (score 0):

As *Christopher Painter* has already pointed out you could use ClickOnce to achieve it, its one of the [Deployment Strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71baz9ah%28v=vs.80%29.ASPX) of the ClickOnce technology.

`Install from the Web or a Network Share`

> Using this strategy, your application is deployed to a Web server or a
>   network file share. When an end user wants to install the application,
>   he or she clicks an icon on a Web page or double-clicks an icon on the
>   file share. The application is then downloaded, installed, and started
>   on the end user's computer. Items are added to the Start menu and the
>   Add/Remove Programs group in the Control Panel.